# Не могу понять почему не печатается name. Что- здесь не так?

Tags: c++

Mне надо добавить данние Cat и распечатать их.

```
       int main() {

            pen* catspen = new pen();
            StreetCat* street = new StreetCat();



            cin >> *street;
            catspen->addStreet(*street);  //add cat
            cout << "\n";

            cout << *catspen;    //print cats in the pen
            cout << "\n";

            delete catspen;

            return 0;
        }

        #ifndef CAT_H
        #define CAT_H
        #include <iostream>
        #include <string>
        using namespace std;

        class cat {

        protected:

            char* name;    //name of cat
            int id;        //id of cat
            double lengthMustache;  //length mustache of cat
            char* color;        //color of cat

        public:
            //Constructors
            cat();   //empty constructor
            cat(char* name,int id,double lengthMustache,char* color);   //constructor
            cat(cat &other);       //copy constructor
            ~cat();     //destructor

            //SETTERS, GETTERS
            void setName(char* name);
            void setId(int id);
            void setLengthMustache(double lengthMustache);
            void setColor(char* color);
            char* getName();
            int getId();
            double getLengthMustache();
            char* getColor();

            //Overloaded oparators
            cat operator = (cat &other); // Overloaded = operator
            friend ostream &operator << (ostream &output, const cat &otherCat);  //Overloaded stream-insertion operator
            friend istream &operator >> (istream &input, cat &otherCat);  //Overloaded stream-extraction operator

        };
        #endif


        #ifndef STREETCAT_H
        #define STREETCAT_H

        class StreetCat : public cat {

        protected:
            int numBattle;

        public:
            StreetCat();    //empty constructor
            StreetCat(char* name, int id, double lengthMustache, char* color, int numBattle);    //constructor
            StreetCat(StreetCat &other);         //copy constructor
            ~StreetCat();     //destructor
            int getNumBattle();    //get number of battle

            //Overloaded oparators
            StreetCat operator = (StreetCat &other); // Overloaded = operator
            friend ostream &operator << (ostream &output, const StreetCat &otherStreetCat);  //Overloaded stream-insertion operator
            friend istream &operator >> (istream &input, StreetCat &otherStreetCat);  //Overloaded stream-extraction operator

        };
        #endif


        #include "cat.h"

    /* Cat definition*/
    cat::cat()          //empty constructor
    {
        this->name = NULL;
        this->id = 0;
        this->lengthMustache = 0.0;
        this->color = NULL;
    }

    cat::cat(char* name,int i, double length, char* color):id(id), lengthMustache(length)    //constructor
    {
        //if (this->name!=NULL) {   
        //  delete this->name;     //delete previouse dynamic memory
        //}
        this->name = new char[strlen(name)+1];
        this->name = _strdup(name);

        //if (this->color != NULL) {
        //  delete this->color;    //delete previouse dynamic memory
        //}
        this->color = new char[strlen(color) + 1];
        this->color = _strdup(color);

    }

    cat::cat(cat &other):id(other.id),lengthMustache(other.lengthMustache)     //copy constructor
    {
        //if (this->name != NULL) {
        //  delete this->name;         //delete previouse dynamic memory
        //}
        this->name = new char[strlen(name) + 1];
        this->name = _strdup(other.name);

        if (this->color != NULL) {
            delete this->color;        //delete previouse dynamic memory
        }
        this->color = new char[strlen(color) + 1];
        this->color = _strdup(other.color);


    }

    cat::~cat()        //destructor
    {
        delete this->name;    //delete dynamic allocated memory of name
        delete this->color;   //delete dynamic allocated memory of color
    }

    void cat::setName(char * n)
    {
        this->name = n;
    }

    void cat::setId(int num)
    {
        this->id = num;
    }

    void cat::setLengthMustache(double length)
    {
        this->lengthMustache = length;
    }

    void cat::setColor(char * c)
    {
        this->color = c;
    }

    char * cat::getName()
    {
        return this->name;
    }

    int cat::getId()
    {
        return this->id;
    }

    double cat::getLengthMustache()
    {
        return this->lengthMustache;
    }

    char * cat::getColor()
    {
        return this->color;
    }

    cat cat::operator=(cat &other)     // Overloaded = operator
    {
            id = other.id;
            lengthMustache = other.lengthMustache;

            //if (this->name != NULL) {
            //  delete this->name;       //delete previouse dynamic memory
            //}
            this->name = new char[strlen(name) + 1];
            this->name = _strdup(other.name);

            if (this->color != NULL) {
                delete this->color;      //delete previouse dynamic memory
            }
            this->color = new char[strlen(color) + 1];
            this->color = _strdup(other.color);

        return *this;
    }

    //Overloaded stream-insertion operator operator
    ostream & operator<<(ostream &output, const cat &otherCat)
    {
        output << "\nName: "<< otherCat.name << "\nID: " << otherCat.id ;
        output << "\nLength mustache: " << otherCat.lengthMustache << "\nColor: " << otherCat.color;
        return output;
    }

    //Overloaded stream-extraction operator
    istream & operator>>(istream &input, cat &otherCat)
    {
        char* name = new char[1024];

        cout << "Enter name of cat: ";
        input >> name;
        otherCat.setName(name);

        double mustacheLength;
        cout << "Enter mustache length of cat: ";
        input >> mustacheLength;
        otherCat.setLengthMustache(mustacheLength);

        char* color = new char[1024];
        cout << "Enter color of cat: ";
        input >> color;
        otherCat.setColor(color);

        delete name;
        delete color;
        return input;
    }

    /* StreetCat definition*/
    StreetCat::StreetCat()  // empty constructor 
    {
        //empty body
    }

    StreetCat::StreetCat(char* name, int id, double lengthMustache, char* color, int battle): cat(name, id, lengthMustache, color)   //constructor
    {
        this->numBattle = battle;
    }

    StreetCat::StreetCat(StreetCat &other): cat(other.name, other.id, other.lengthMustache, other.color)    //copy constructor
    {
        this->numBattle = other.numBattle;
    }

    StreetCat::~StreetCat()    //destructor
    {
        //empty body
    }

    int StreetCat::getNumBattle()
    {
        return this->numBattle;
    }

    StreetCat StreetCat::operator=(StreetCat &other)      // Overloaded = operator
    {
        //given cat variables
        this->setName(other.getName());
        this->setId(other.getId());
        this->setLengthMustache(other.getLengthMustache());
        this->setColor(other.getColor());

        this->numBattle = other.numBattle;   //new variable of street cat
        return *this;
    }

    //Overloaded stream-insertion operator operator
    ostream &operator<<(ostream &output, const StreetCat &otherStreetCat)
    {
        output << "\nName: " << *otherStreetCat.name << "\nID: " << otherStreetCat.id;
        output << "\nLength mustache: " << otherStreetCat.lengthMustache << "\nColor: " << *otherStreetCat.color;
        output << "\nNumber battles in which he participated is: " << otherStreetCat.numBattle << "\n";
        return output;
    }

    //Overloaded stream-extraction operator
    istream &operator>>(istream & input, StreetCat & otherStreetCat)
    {
        char* nameCat = new char[1024];
        cout << "Enter name of cat: ";
        input >> nameCat;
        otherStreetCat.setName(nameCat);

        double mustacheLength;
        cout << "Enter mustache length of cat: ";
        input >> mustacheLength;
        otherStreetCat.setLengthMustache(mustacheLength);

        char* color = new char[1024];
        cout << "Enter color of cat: ";
        input >> color;
        otherStreetCat.setColor(color);

        delete nameCat;
        delete color;

        cout << "Enter number of battle: ";
        input >> otherStreetCat.numBattle;
        return input;
    }



    #ifndef PEN_H
    #define PEN_H
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include "cat.h"
    using namespace std;

    class pen {

    public:
        int numOfCats;           //number of cats in pen
        int numOfFreeCages;      //number available cages
        StreetCat** arrStreet;   //array of Street Cats
        int count;               //count the id
        int numOfStreetCats;     //number of street cats

        pen();          //empty constructor
        ~pen();         //destructor
        bool place();   //function checks if we have available place in the pen
        bool addStreet(StreetCat &arrStreet);    //add the street cat to the pen
        friend ostream &operator << (ostream &output, const pen &otherPen);  //Overloaded stream-insertion operator

    };
    #endif


#include "pen.h"

pen::pen()          //empty constructor
{
    this->numOfCats = 0;          //total cats is 0
    this->numOfFreeCages = 5;     //total cages is 5
    this->arrStreet = NULL;       //empty array
    this->count = 1;              //count the id,strat from 1
    this->numOfStreetCats = 0;    //number of street cats is 0
}

pen::~pen()      //destructor
{
    for (int i = 0; i < this->numOfStreetCats; i++) {
        delete this->arrStreet[i];   //delete current street cats pointers
    }
    delete[] this->arrStreet;    //delete dynamic allocated memory of arrStreet

}

bool pen::place()      //function checks if we have available place in the pen
{
    bool result = false;
    if (numOfFreeCages>0) {  
        result = true;
    }

    return result;
}

bool pen::addStreet(StreetCat &arrStreet)
{
    bool result = false;

    if (!place()) {       //if we don`t have place in cat pen
        cout << "Pen is full!\n";
    }

    else {     //we have place in cat pen

        arrStreet.setId(this->count);    //set the id to cat

        if (this->numOfStreetCats == 0) { //if we don't have cats

            this->arrStreet = new StreetCat*[1];
            this->arrStreet[0] = new StreetCat(arrStreet);

            this->numOfStreetCats++; 
            this->numOfCats++; 
            this->numOfFreeCages--; 
            this->count++; 

            result = true;
        }
        else if (this->numOfStreetCats > 0) {   //if we have cats

            StreetCat** temp = new StreetCat*[this->numOfStreetCats];
            for (int i = 0; i < this->numOfStreetCats; i++)   //copy objects from arrStreet to temp
            {
                temp[i] = new StreetCat(*this->arrStreet[i]);
                delete this->arrStreet[i];
            }
            delete[] this->arrStreet;   // delete the arrStreet cats array

            this->arrStreet = new StreetCat*[this->numOfStreetCats + 1];   // re-create it with a size +1
            for (int i = 0; i < this->numOfStreetCats; i++) {    // copy objects from temp to arrStreet
                this->arrStreet[i] = new StreetCat(*temp[i]);
                delete temp[i];
            }

            this->arrStreet[this->numOfStreetCats] = new StreetCat(arrStreet);  //add element given in the function
            delete[] temp;   // delete the temp array

            this->numOfStreetCats++; 
            this->numOfCats++; 
            this->numOfFreeCages--; 
            this->count++; 

            result = true;
        }

    }

    return result;
}

//Overloaded stream-insertion operator
ostream &operator << (ostream &output, const pen &otherPen)
{
    output << "Total cats in the pen:\n";

    if (otherPen.numOfStreetCats==0)    //if we don't have street cats
    {
        output << "Don't have the street cats in pen!\n";
    }
    else {
        output << "\nThe Street cats: ";
        for (int i = 0; i < otherPen.numOfStreetCats; i++)      // print the Street Cats
        {   
            output << *otherPen.arrStreet[i] << " ";
        }
    }

    return output;
}
```

Comment: У вас просто бешеное количество ляпсусов... _strdup сам выделяет память, так что выделенную через new память вы теряете. strdup выделяет память через malloc, ее надо освобождать через free. Таскать this-> можно, но смысла - никакого. Присвоение указателя  this->name = n; приведет скорее всего к неприятностям...

Comment: да и в целом это очередная помесь дремучих сей с плюсами

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вобщем, у вас переписывать - не переписать. Котов я вам исправил, дальше правьте сами... Постарайтесь понять, почему и как исправлено то или иное.

И - вам обязательно хранить строки в `char*`? Через `string` было бы проще...

Еще - вам в друзья записывать `<<` и `>>` не нужно, раз уж у вас есть все геттеры-сеттеры. Оставил как есть. Это просто минимальное причесывание, но никак не показатель, что вот так надо писать - просто нет времени, чтоб исправить как следует.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <limits>
using namespace std;

// Вспомогательная функция, чтоб не таскать через весь код выделение/копирование...    
inline char* newString(const char * s)
{
    char * t = (s) ? new char[strlen(s)+1] : 0;
    if (s) strcpy(t,s);
    return t;
}


class cat
{

private:

    char*  name;    //name of cat
    int    id;        //id of cat
    double lengthMustache;  //length mustache of cat
    char*  color;        //color of cat

  public:
    //Constructors
    cat();   //empty constructor
    cat(char* name, int id, double lengthMustache,
        char* color); //constructor
    cat(const cat& other);       //copy constructor
    virtual ~cat();     //destructor

    //SETTERS, GETTERS
    void setName(char* name_) { delete[] name; name = newString(name_); }
    void setId(int id_)       { id = id_; }
    void setLengthMustache(double length) { lengthMustache = length; }
    void setColor(char*color_){ delete[] color; color = newString(color_); }
    const char* getName() const { return name; }
    int getId() const           { return id; }
    double getLengthMustache() const { return lengthMustache; }
    const char* getColor() const { return color; }

    //Overloaded oparators
    cat& operator = (const cat& other); // Overloaded = operator

    friend ostream& operator << (ostream& output,
                                 const cat& otherCat);  //Overloaded stream-insertion operator
    friend istream& operator >> (istream& input,
                                 cat& otherCat);  //Overloaded stream-extraction operator

};


class StreetCat : public cat
{

  protected:
    int numBattle;
  public:
      StreetCat():cat(){};    //empty constructor
      StreetCat(char* name, int id, double lengthMustache, char* color,
                int numBattle):cat(name,id,lengthMustache,color),
          numBattle(numBattle){}
                //constructor
      StreetCat(const StreetCat& other):cat(other),         //copy constructor
          numBattle(numBattle){}
      ~StreetCat(){};     //destructor

      int getNumBattle() const { return numBattle; }   //get number of battle

    //Overloaded oparators
    StreetCat& operator = (const StreetCat& other); // Overloaded = operator
    friend ostream& operator << (ostream& output,
                                 const StreetCat&
                                 otherStreetCat);  //Overloaded stream-insertion operator
    friend istream& operator >> (istream& input,
                                 StreetCat& otherStreetCat);  //Overloaded stream-extraction operator

};

/* Cat definition*/
cat::cat()          //empty constructor
:name(nullptr),id(0),lengthMustache(0.0),color(nullptr)
{}

cat::cat(char* name, int id, double length, char* color)
:id(id),lengthMustache(length),    //constructor
name(newString(name)),color(newString(color))
{}

cat::cat(const cat& other)
:id(other.id),lengthMustache(other.lengthMustache),     //copy constructor
name(newString(other.name)),color(newString(other.color))
{}

cat::~cat()        //destructor
{
    delete[] name;    //delete dynamic allocated memory of name
    delete[] color;   //delete dynamic allocated memory of color
}

cat& cat::operator=(const cat& other)     // Overloaded = operator
{
    id = other.id;
    lengthMustache = other.lengthMustache;
    setName(other.name);
    setColor(other.color);
    return *this;
}

//Overloaded stream-insertion operator operator
ostream& operator<<(ostream& output, const cat& otherCat)
{
    output << "\nName: " << otherCat.name << "\nID: " << otherCat.id ;
    output << "\nLength mustache: " << otherCat.lengthMustache <<
           "\nColor: " << otherCat.color;
    return output;
}

//Overloaded stream-extraction operator
istream& operator>>(istream& input, cat& otherCat)
{
    char* name = new char[1024];
    cout << "Enter name of cat: ";
    input.getline(name,1024);
    otherCat.setName(name);
    cout << "Enter mustache length of cat: ";
    input >> otherCat.lengthMustache;
    input.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    cout << "Enter color of cat: ";
    input.getline(name,1024);
    otherCat.setColor(name);
    delete[] name;
    return input;
}

StreetCat& StreetCat::operator=(const StreetCat&
                               other)      // Overloaded = operator
{
    this->cat::operator=(other);
    numBattle = other.numBattle;   //new variable of street cat
    return *this;
}

//Overloaded stream-insertion operator operator
ostream& operator<<(ostream& output, const StreetCat& otherStreetCat)
{
    output << static_cast<const cat&>(otherStreetCat);
    output << "\nNumber battles in which he participated is: " <<
           otherStreetCat.numBattle << "\n";
    return output;
}

//Overloaded stream-extraction operator
istream& operator>>(istream& input, StreetCat& otherStreetCat)
{
    input >> static_cast<cat&>(otherStreetCat);
    cout << "Enter number of battle: ";
    input >> otherStreetCat.numBattle;
    input.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    return input;
}
```

Comment: спасибо я буду исправлять